# Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm having problems with misconfigured Redux after merging contents of multiple files into one to serve as config for Redux.

How to resolve `store`, while keeping this in one file?

> Unhandled JS Exception: Could not find "store" in either the context
>   or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a
>   , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)".

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as screenActions from './redux/actions/screenActions';

import * as reducers from './redux/stores/reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);

import RootContainer from './redux/views/containers/rootContainer';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { state, actions } = this.props;
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RootContainer />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    state: state.reducer
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(screenActions, dispatch)
  })
)(App);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

- Provider, [***passes the store***](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.md#passing-the-store) to the component nested within it and generally only needed to be applied to the **root** component (in your case `<RootContainer>`
- `connect` connect with the component providing store and *not* the component that has store provided to it.

#### SUGGESTED SOLUTION:

*MOVE* the **`connect`** to the **`<RootContainer>`** component file instead, and pass `connect` the RootContainer and *not* the App component:

```
export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    state: state.reducer
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(screenActions, dispatch)
  })
)(RootContainer);  // <<--- here :)
```

---

#### UPDATE:

Given the OP wants to achieve all of this in the same file, you'll have to create a React element that represents your Redux container created from connect, so:

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as screenActions from './redux/actions/screenActions';

import * as reducers from './redux/stores/reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);

import RootContainer from './redux/views/containers/rootContainer';

// name has to be capitalised for React to recognise it as an element in JSX
const ConnectedRoot = connect(
  (state) => ({
    state: state.reducer
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(screenActions, dispatch)
  })
)(RootContainer);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { state, actions } = this.props;
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRoot />    <------USE IT HERE
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That helps, but changing the line itself didn't completely solve problem. Problem still remains around the lines `<Provider store={store}>
<RootContainer /></Provider>`.

Comment: Fine, that brings me back to two files. I was asking if it's possible to move this specific part with `connect()` into the `<App>` component.

Comment: Scratch my last comment, my initial suggestion should have worked.  I take it you are receiving the same error exception message?

Comment: No, it didn't. It kept showing the same error. Probably because `connect()` was being called after `<RootContainer />` being instantiated.

Comment: Ah, most likely has to do with `export default`, which if in a separate file would mean than the export would be a connected container.  Here the export doesn't make sense.

Comment: Meaning I should remove `default` from `export default class RootContainer`?

Comment: Since you define a separate file for <RootContainer/> I'd just move the connect function in there

Comment: Removing the `default` won't mean anything.  What that code is effectively trying to do is provide an export object for the current file.  You're probably aware you can have default exports, or name exports.  What you want to do is set the the return value of connect to a local function whose name has a captial letter, and use that in place of <RootContainer>.  I'll update my example

Comment: Yeah, probably, there is not much to gain from merging those files.

Comment: Not suggesting to merge them.  The way I would do this is to copy your original snippet, cut the connect code from it, paste it in the RootComponent file and change App to RootContainer in the `connect`.

Comment: Since you want to do the connect in the same file as where the provider is defined, you'd have to provide the result of the `connect` function as a local React element made from making the `connect` call rather than exporting it (which doesn't make  sense)

Comment: i have implemented reactjs.net with redux and getting error
JsScriptException: Script threw an exception.
JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.JsRt.JsErrorHelpers.ThrowIfError(JsErrorCode errorCode)

JsRuntimeException: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Login)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Login) in connect options.

can you please help me
Thanks in advance .

Comment: @SayedAzharuddin it’s difficult to provide any further help without more context. It would help if you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example to outline your issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as a guide on how to do this

Answer (score 2):

I had such a problem when I used:

```
import connect from "react-redux/lib/connect/connect";
```

instead of that, use:

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
```

Comment: This answer might not apply to OP's post, but it solved my issue after upgrading react-redux which was exactly that: a wrong, forgotten absolute path import. Than you!!!

Answer (score -2):

In your root index put the provider.

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>,
```