# Provider unable to access redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have been trying to access the states of my redux store from a component for a while now and i keep getting this error all the time. I have followed multiple tutorials on how to properly connect a component with the redux store but no luck. Below are snippets of my component, redux config and the error message.

**Error Message**
**Invariant Violation: Could not find "store: in either the context or props of "Connect(HomeScreen)". Either wrap the root component in the , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Homescreen)".
This error is located at:
 in Connect(HomeScreen) (at Navigation.js:51)**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import configureStore from "./src/Store/configureStore"
import React from "react"

const store= configureStore()

const RNRedux= () => (
<Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
</Provider>
);



AppRegistry.registerComponent('Fluffy', () => RNRedux);
```

Below is the config Store

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from "redux"
import homeReducer from "./Reducers/homeReducer"

const rootReducer= combineReducers({
    home: homeReducer
 })

const configureStore = () => {
   return createStore(rootReducer)
 }

export default configureStore
```

Below is the reducer

```
import {SHOW_ITEMS} from "../Actions/actionTypes"

const initialState= {
cakes:[

    {
        id: 1,
        name:"Baked blur",
        image: require("../../Assets/bake-baked-blur-461279.jpg"),
        price: 40, 
        flavor:["chocolate", "strawberrry","vanilla", "Coffee"],
        size: ["14inches","12inches","10inches","8inches","6inches"], 
        toppings: ["maltesers","gummybears","mint","mentos","smarties"]
     },

    {
        id: 2,
        name:"Blueberry Cake",
        image: require("../../Assets/bakery-baking-blueberries-291528.jpg"),
        price: 15, 
        flavor:["chocolate", "strawberrry","vanilla", "Coffee"],
        size: ["14inches","12inches","10inches","8inches","6inches"], 
        toppings: ["maltesers","gummybears","mint","mentos","smarties"]
     },

    {
        id: 3,
        name:"Birthday Cake",
        image: require("../../Assets/baking-berry-birthday-357748.jpg"),
        price: 30, 
        flavor:["chocolate", "strawberrry","vanilla", "Coffee"],
        size: ["14inches","12inches","10inches","8inches","6inches"], 
        toppings: ["maltesers","gummybears","mint","mentos","smarties"]
     },

    {
        id: 4,
        name:"Blackberry Cake",
        image: require("../../Assets/berries-berry-cake-434243.jpg"),
        price: 60, 
        flavor:["chocolate", "strawberrry","vanilla", "Coffee"],
        size: ["14inches","12inches","10inches","8inches","6inches"], 
        toppings: ["maltesers","gummybears","mint","mentos","smarties"]
     },

    {
        id: 5,
        name:"Cheesecake",
        image: require("../../Assets/berries-cake-cheesecake-85766.jpg"),
        price: 70, 
        flavor:["chocolate", "strawberrry","vanilla", "Coffee"],
        size: ["14inches","12inches","10inches","8inches","6inches"], 
        toppings: ["maltesers","gummybears","mint","mentos","smarties"]
     },

    {
        id: 6,
        name:"Blueberry Fudge",
        image: require("../../Assets/berry-blackberry-blueberry-315707.jpg"),
        price: 20, 
        flavor:["chocolate", "strawberrry","vanilla", "Coffee"],
        size: ["14inches","12inches","10inches","8inches","6inches"], 
        toppings: ["maltesers","gummybears","mint","mentos","smarties"]
     },
     {
        id: 7,
        name:"Pancake",
        image: require("../../Assets/birthday-birthday-cake-cake-140831.jpg"),
        price: 70, 
        flavor:["chocolate", "strawberrry","vanilla", "Coffee"],
        size: ["14inches","12inches","10inches","8inches","6inches"], 
        toppings: ["maltesers","gummybears","mint","mentos","smarties"]
     },
     {
        id: 8,
        name:"Vanilla Fudge",
        image: require("../../Assets/birthday-birthday-cake-cake-140831.jpg"),
        price: 70, 
        flavor:["chocolate", "strawberrry","vanilla", "Coffee"],
        size: ["14inches","12inches","10inches","8inches","6inches"], 
        toppings: ["maltesers","gummybears","mint","mentos","smarties"]
     },
     {
        id: 9,
        name:"Strawberry Fudge",
        image: require("../../Assets/blur-cake-cheesecake-219293.jpg"),
        price: 70, 
        flavor:["chocolate", "strawberrry","vanilla", "Coffee"],
        size: ["14inches","12inches","10inches","8inches","6inches"], 
        toppings: ["maltesers","gummybears","mint","mentos","smarties"]
     },
     {
        id: 10,
        name:"Mango Slice",
        image: require("../../Assets/blur-cake-close-up-355290.jpg"),
        price: 70, 
        flavor:["chocolate", "strawberrry","vanilla", "Coffee"],
        size: ["14inches","12inches","10inches","8inches","6inches"], 
        toppings: 
    ["maltesers","gummybears","mint","mentos","smarties"]
     },

],

Customizables:[
    {
        Flavor:["chocolate", "strawberrry","vanilla", "Coffee"],
        Sizes: ["14inches","12inches","10inches","8inches","6inches"], 
        Toppings: ["maltesers","gummybears","mint","mentos","smarties"]

    }
]
}

const homeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case SHOW_ITEMS:
        return {
            ...state
        }
        default:
        return state
    }


}

export default homeReducer
```

And below is the Component i connected to the store

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, Platform, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Dimensions} from "react-native"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons" 

import SpecialOffer from "../Components/homeScreenComp/SOS/specialOffers"
import initState from "../Store/LocalStore/local"
import ListItem from "../Components/homeScreenComp/listItem"
import Swiper from "../Components/homeScreenComp/specialSwiper"

 const Width = Dimensions.get("window").width


class HomeScreen extends Component {

  // state = initState

  selectionHandler = (key) => {
    // const custom = this.state.Customizables
    const selPlace = this.props.cakes.find(cakes => {
      return cakes.id === key
    })

    this.props.navigator.push({
      screen: "fluffy.OrderScreen",
      passProps:{
        selectedCake: selPlace,
     //   Customs: custom
      }
    })
  }


  static navigatorStyle = {
    navBarHidden: true,
    drawUnderNavBar: true,
    // navBarTranslucent: true
  };

  render() {


    return (
      <View style={styles.cover}>
      {/* HEADER */}
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <View>
          <Icon name={Platform.OS === "android"? "md-menu": "ios-menu"} size={30}/>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Fluffy Dreams</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Icon name={Platform.OS === "android"? "md-notifications": "ios-notifications"} size={30}/>
        </View>
      </View>
      {/* SWIPER */}
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>

      <Swiper />
        {/* SPECIAL OFFERS */}
    <SpecialOffer Dimension={Width}/>

  {/* MARKET */}
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{height: 50, width: Width, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', borderWidth: 2, borderColor: "black", marginTop: 10, alignItems: "center"}}>
    <View style={{padding: 5, marginLeft: 5,}}>
    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold"}}> MARKET</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={{padding: 5, marginRight: 5,}}>
    <Icon name={Platform.OS === "android"? "md-color-filter": "ios-color-filter"} size={30}/>
    </View>
  </View>

<ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} overScrollMode="auto" contentContainerStyle={styles.itemWrapper}>
  {this.props.cakes.map((cakes, index) => (
      <ListItem onPress={this.selectionHandler} key ={index} cakes={cakes} />
    ))}
  </ScrollView>


  </View>

  </ScrollView>
  </View>

    )
  }
}


const styles= StyleSheet.create({

  cover:{
    flex: 1,

  },
  header:{
    backgroundColor:"red", 
    height: 70,
     width: "100%",
      flexDirection: 'row', 
      justifyContent: "space-between",
       alignItems: 'center',
      }
  ,
  text:{
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },

    itemWrapper:{
      alignItems: "center",
      flex: 1,
      width: Width-5 ,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      justifyContent: "center",

    }
  // OfferCarousel:{
  //   flex:3,
  //   flexDirection: 'row',
  //   //  backgroundColor: "yellow"
  // }
})

const mapStateToProps= state => {
  return{
    cakes: state.home.cakes
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen)
```

App.js

```
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import {Navigation} from "react-native-navigation"

import OnboardingScreen from "./src/screens/OnboardingScreen"
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen"
import NewsScreen from "./src/screens/NewsScreen"
import ProfileScreen from "./src/screens/ProfileScreen"
import CartScreen from "./src/screens/CartScreen"
import ProfileInfoScreen from "./src/screens/ProfileInfoScreen"
import OrderScreen from "./src/screens/OrderScreen"
import configureStore from "./src/Store/configureStore"

const store = configureStore()

Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.OnboardingScreen", ()=> OnboardingScreen,Provider,store)
Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.HomeScreen",
 ()=>HomeScreen,
 store,
 Provider
 )
Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.NewsScreen", ()=> NewsScreen,
store,
Provider)

Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.ProfileScreen",
 ()=> ProfileScreen,
 Provider,
 store)

Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.CartScreen",
 ()=> CartScreen,
 Provider,
 store)

Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.ProfileInfoScreen", 
()=>ProfileInfoScreen,
Provider,
store)

Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.OrderScreen", 
()=> OrderScreen,
Provider,
store)

 export default ()=> Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
screen : {
  screen: "fluffy.OnboardingScreen",
}
})
```

Comment: What is in App.js ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892553/could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-props-of-connectapp)

Comment: Also have u imported this component inside `App.js`? If not I guess it wont work

Comment: Yes, i did import it in my app.js

Comment: check out the edit i just added on the app.js file to the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `App.js` file. You're not exporting anything as default in your `App.js` file so you're essentially wrapping the provider around something `undefined`.

I'm not familiar with using `react-native-navigation` like the way you're using it now. But given a quick look at what you're doing, you'll need to `export default Navigation;` at the end of your `App.js` file.

Comment: ohh thanks a lot Barry for pulling my attention to that file. I found out that a lot of imports have been missing. Let me update the file right away.

Comment: Finally got passed that error! Phew! I now unfortunately just welcome another one. After successfully updating that file, i now get the error below even though i exported the startSingleScreen navigation function as my default.
"ExceptionsManager.js:71 Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
"

Comment: It might be that you just need to `export default Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({ ... });` rather than `export default () => Navi...`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue or not but in your export default HomeScreen you should have

    `export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(HomeScreen)`

else it will throw you an error.

null takes place of your mapDispatchToProps because connect will be looking for it even if you do not have it

Comment: Thanks Jacob, but i have tried that before. I think the 'null' argument is normally passed to the connect function if mapDispatchToProps is the only argument called because it is the second argument native to the function.

Comment: @Jacob the second argument for `mapDispatchToProps` is optional, that wouldn't throw an error.