# react native updating redux store from app.js not working

Tags: react-native, react-redux, geolocation, redux-persist

https://snack.expo.io/@mparvez19861/redux-example

I have below code in app.js in

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import firebase from './FireBaseSetup/Firebase'
// import DrawerNavigatorExample from './Navigations';
import Navigator from './Navigator'
import Permissions from 'react-native-permissions'
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import PermissionsList from './Utitliy/PermissionsList'
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { store, persistor, setCurrentLocation } from './redux/app-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import SplashScreen from './screens/SplashScreen'


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setCurrentLocation: (location) => { dispatch(setCurrentLocation(location)) }
    };
}
const ConnectedApp = connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Navigator);
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            latitude: null,
            longitude: null,
            error: null,

        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.getContacts();
        await new PermissionsList().requestLocationPermission();
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                // this.setState({
                //     latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                //     longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                //     error: null,
                // });
                this.props.setCurrentLocation(position);
                firebase.firestore().collection('locations').doc('8686').set({
                    locations: position
                })
            },
            (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000, distanceFilter: 100 }
        );
        this.watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
            (position) => {
                // this.setState({
                //     latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                //     longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                //     error: null,
                // });
                this.props.setCurrentLocation(position);
                firebase.firestore().collection('locations').doc('8686').set({
                    locations: position
                })
            },
            (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
            { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 10000, distanceFilter: 1 },
        );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        Geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <ConnectedApp />
                    </View>
                </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
});
```

**Navigator.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight, Image } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator , createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  Button,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

// import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
// import { store } from '../redux/app-redux';


import Screen2 from './screens/Screen2';
import SplashScreen from './screens/SplashScreen'
import Login from './screens/Login'
import SignOutScreen from './screens/SignOutScreen'
import screendesign from './screens/screendesign'
import EmailPwdLogin from './screens/EmailPwdLogin'
import friends from './screens/friends'

import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import SignupScreen from './screens/SignupScreen';




const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  // { SignIn: SignInScreen }
  // SignIn: { screen: EmailPwdLogin }
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Signup: { screen: SignupScreen },
  });
const drNav = createDrawerNavigator(
  {

     friends: {
      screen: friends
    },
    Screen2: {
        screen: Screen2
      },
     SignOut: {
      screen: SignOutScreen
    }
  }
)

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    // screendesign: screendesign,
    SplashScreen: SplashScreen,
    App: drNav,
    AuthStack: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen',
  }
));
```

**Redux file**

```
const setCurrentLocation = (location) => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(location))
  return {
    type: "setCurrentLocation",
    value: location
  };
};

export { setCurrentLocation };
```

But this **setCurrentLocation** is not being fired from app.js

please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to dispatch a redux action from App.js which is the entry point of your application and where you initialise your redux store. You can use `this.props.setCurrentLocation(position)` from any connected component **within** the Provider component, but App.js is outside of it.

So you need to call it like so:

```
store.dispatch(setCurrentLocation(position))
```

I tried to run your snack to see if you have any other issues but it throws an error.

Hope this helps

Comment: Okay... So in app.js there is no mean to mapping dispatch or state props right?

Comment: Generally you can use mapstate / mapdispatch for components that are wrapped inside the redux Provider component. Usually this is where you need to dispatch actions and use data from redux store. In the edge cases you need to use the redux store in the entry point component then this is how you do it. This is my understanding at least :)

Answer (score 1):

You forget to connect `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: @Md. Parvez please accept the answer so other can get help

Comment: It is there, it is there, just wrongly updated the line inpost

Comment: I didn't  use mapStateToProps as I don't need to get the value from store, I ony need to updated

Comment: Getting errro Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)"

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam this answer is correct. You need to connect store to `App`, not `Navigator` to provide `setCurrentLocation` to `App` component.

Comment: the code  provided was not working, so by doing google I made changes, Just FYI i am using redux persist on app

Comment: I changed as per suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892553/could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-props-of-connectapp