# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I get this error when I try and fetch data and `componentDidMount`. How can I fix this and is it the best place to fetch data in my app?

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ImageBackground
} from "react-native";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import store from "./config/configureStore";
import { fetchData, loadState } from "./actions/videos";
import AppNavigator from "./navigation/AppNavigator";
import NavigationService from "./navigation/actions";

const Root = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <AppNavigator
        ref={navigatorRef => {
          NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
        }}
      />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchData } = this.props;
    fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("./assets/images/TC_background.jpg")}
        style={styles.container}
      >
        <Root />
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchData())
});
const mapStateToProps = state => {};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    fontFamily: "lato-regular",
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover"
  }
});
```

Comment: I think your setup is wrong. You should use the Provider inside your main App component which gets passed the store. Then into your Root component you use the connect function in order to access the store. You can find more details in this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892553/could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-props-of-connectapp

Answer (score 0):

Do you have reducer and store, yes?

if you have try like this

Also, you can write your dispatch method like this

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Also you can write your dispatch method like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
 fetchData,
}
```