# React Native redux using connect and store in the same component

Tags: react-native, redux, store

I'm working on a react native app, i use redux to manage global state.
I want to store a state in the app component where i call the store :

```
/* eslint-disable global-require */
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native'
// ***************************************************
import AppContainer from './eXpand/Components/Navigation';
// ***************************************************
import { AppLoading } from 'expo'
import * as Font from 'expo-font'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import {
  cacheAssets,
  cacheFonts
} from './eXpand/Helpers/Defaults/AssetsCaching'
import store from '~/Store/store'
import registerForPushNotificationsAsync from './eXpand/Components/Services/notifications';

// Local Import
import { setUserGsm } from '~/Store/actions';

class App extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isReady: false,
      GSM: null
    }
  }

  /**
 * Demande d'autorisation pour accéder au token du GSM et l'envoyer vers l'api
 */
  async registerForPush() {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
      Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
    );
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      return;
    }
    let gsm = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();

    if (this._isMounted) {
      this.setState({
        GSM: gsm
      });
    }

    console.log("### GSM TOKEN GSM ###")
    console.log(this.state.GSM)
    console.log("#####################")
  }

  /**
   * Add Font with Asynchronous Method
   */

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("##########  COMPONENT DID MOUNT   ############")
    this._isMounted = true;
    if (this._isMounted) {
      this.registerForPush()
      this.props.setUserGsm(this.state.GSM)
    }
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    await Font.loadAsync({
      // ROBOTO
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      // SFUIDisplay
      SFUIDisplayBlack: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Black.otf'),
      SFUIDisplayBold: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Bold.otf'),
      SFUIDisplayHeavy: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Heavy.otf'),
      SFUIDisplayLight: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Light.otf'),
      SFUIDisplayMedium: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Medium.otf'),
      SFUIDisplaySemibold: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Semibold.otf'),
      SFUIDisplayThin: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Thin.otf'),
      SFUIDisplayUltralight: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Ultralight.otf'),
      // MyriadPro
      MYRIADPROBOLD: require('^/Fonts/MyriadPro-Bold.otf'),
      MyriadProBlackSemiCn: require('^/Fonts/MyriadPro-BlackSemiCn.otf'),
      MyriadProBoldSemiExtended: require('^/Fonts/MyriadPro-BoldSemiExtended.ttf'),
      ...Ionicons.font,
      // PTSans
      PTSansRegular: require('^/Fonts/PTSans-Regular.ttf'),
      PTSansBold: require('^/Fonts/PTSans-Bold.ttf'),
      PTSansItalic: require('^/Fonts/PTSans-Italic.ttf'),
    })
    this.setState({ isReady: true })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    console.log("##########  COMPONENT WILL MOUNT   ############")
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  handleBackButton() {
    return true;
  }

  async _loadAssetsAsync() {
    const imageAssets = cacheAssets([require('^/Logos/expanded.png')])

    const fontAssets = cacheFonts({
      // ROBOTO
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      // SFUIDisplay
      SFUIDisplayBlack: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Black.otf'),
      SFUIDisplayBold: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Bold.otf'),
      SFUIDisplayHeavy: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Heavy.otf'),
      SFUIDisplayLight: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Light.otf'),
      SFUIDisplayMedium: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Medium.otf'),
      SFUIDisplaySemibold: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Semibold.otf'),
      SFUIDisplayThin: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Thin.otf'),
      SFUIDisplayUltralight: require('^/Fonts/SFUIDisplay-Ultralight.otf'),
      // MyriadPro
      MYRIADPROBOLD: require('^/Fonts/MyriadPro-Bold.otf'),
      MyriadProBlackSemiCn: require('^/Fonts/MyriadPro-BlackSemiCn.otf'),
      MyriadProBoldSemiExtended: require('^/Fonts/MyriadPro-BoldSemiExtended.ttf'),
      // PTSans
      PTSansRegular: require('^/Fonts/PTSans-Regular.ttf'),
      PTSansBold: require('^/Fonts/PTSans-Bold.ttf'),
      PTSansItalic: require('^/Fonts/PTSans-Italic.ttf'),
    })

    await Promise.all([imageAssets, fontAssets])
  }

  render() {
    const Root = () => {
      if (!this.state.isReady) {
        return (
          <AppLoading
            startAsync={this._loadAssetsAsync}
            onFinish={() => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
          />
        )
      }
      return <AppContainer />
    }

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Root />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  GSM: state.GSM
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setUserGsm: (GSM) => {
    dispatch(setUserGsm(GSM));
  }
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(App);
```

I get this error :

Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.

Comment: Have a look on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892553/could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-props-of-connectapp) in stackoverflow. That might help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it this way.

The react-redux `Provider` is passing store to the react-redux `connect`. And you are using `connect` in component which is not wrapped (somewhere in React component tree) in `Provider` (the your component itself is rendering `Provider`, which is too late).